# How can I disable pings in Apache::DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, persistence, dbi, mod-perl2

I have a problem disabling validation of the connection in `Apache::DBI`.
From the [perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~abh/Apache-DBI-1.09/lib/Apache/DBI.pm#CONFIGURATION):

> Apache::DBI->setPingTimeOut($data_source,
>   $timeout)
>
> This configures the usage of the ping
>   method, to validate a connection.
>   Setting the timeout to 0 will always
>   validate the database connection using
>   the ping method (default). Setting the
>   timeout < 0 will de-activate the
>   validation of the database handle.

I tried calling `setPingTimeOut` with the same $data_source as in `connect()` but it didn't work. Did anyone manage to disable the pings?

Comment: can you post your $data_source? (With anything secret suitably obfuscated.)

Comment: @martin: I connect using this dsn: `DBI:mysql:database=dbname;host=localhost`. I tried this one with $timeout = -1 but to no avail. I also tried `dbi:mysql:dbname`

Comment: in the code it looks like only dsn matching regexp /dbi:\w+:.*/ will register ping timeouts successfully.  Your second dsn looks plausible.  Note the comment "use a DSN without attribute settings specified within" for the setPingTimeOut function.

Comment: @martin: It seems like this regex match causes the problem. After I changed dsn to `dbi:mysql:database=dbname;host=localhost` it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify, the [code](http://search.cpan.org/~abh/Apache-DBI-1.09/lib/Apache/DBI.pm) has:

```
# use a DSN without attribute settings specified within !
sub setPingTimeOut {
    my $class       = shift;
    my $data_source = shift;
    my $timeout     = shift;

    # sanity check
    if ($data_source =~ /dbi:\w+:.*/ and $timeout =~ /\-*\d+/) {
        $PingTimeOut{$data_source} = $timeout;
    }
}
```

Note the 'sanity check'. Hence ping timeout for a data source name with uppercase 'DBI:' will be silently ignored.